# Creating a button in the maximum size when scrollbars are not visible yet

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jscrollpane

I am trying to create very simple class. The goal is to create a button in the maximum size when scrollbars are not visible yet. My code doesn`t work. The condition pane.getVerticalScrollBar().isVisible() returns true even if the scrollbar is not visible. I wonder why and how can I fix it?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JButton button = new JButton("Hello");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    final JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    buttons.add(button);
    buttons.revalidate();
    final JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(buttons);
    pane.getViewport().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            System.out.println("*******************************************************************");
            System.out.println("Vertical visible? " + pane.getVerticalScrollBar().isVisible());
            System.out.println("Horizontal visible? " + pane.getHorizontalScrollBar().isVisible());
            if (!pane.getVerticalScrollBar().isVisible() && !pane.getHorizontalScrollBar().isVisible()) {
                button.setSize(button.getWidth() + 1, button.getHeight() + 1);
                buttons.revalidate();
                pane.revalidate();
            } else {
                button.setSize(button.getWidth() - 1, button.getHeight() - 1);
                buttons.revalidate();
                pane.revalidate();
                pane.getViewport().removeChangeListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
    panel.add(pane);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't play with the set size method.

If you want the button to occupy all the space available then use either:

```
frame.add(button); // height/width will be max
frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // only width will be max
```

Let the layout managers do the job for you.

Edit:

> I have another class which scale img in the label and I want to find the best value for scale to make it maximalized as possible

Create a custom panel and dynamically draw the image at the size of the panel. Then it will automatically scale based on the space available.

See [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) as an example of this approach.

Comment: I have created this example with button to simplify my problem. Actually instead of button I want to use label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img)) in pane.

Comment: I have another class which scale img in the label and I want to find the best value for scale to make it maximalized as possible as it can be with scrollbars invisible at the same time.

Comment: I don't know the size of the image in advance so I scale it to the minimum size and then I am testing if scrollbars are visible, if not, I make the img bigger and again test it until one of scrollbars appears. Then I set the img to the previous size when scrollbars wasn't visible yet.